# Css box-sizing and jquery width not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, fluid-layout

I'm been going over this for hours and can't work out why it's not working accurately.. I'm using a mix of fixed and fluid columns, width box-sizing and borders and a width set on Jquery. I want the left column to be 170px and the middle and right to be 50% minus the left column. But for some reason, the borders overlap and middle and right don't have the same width? Can anyone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/9LGA9/7/

```
  $('#middle').width(function () {
         return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - 85;
     });

     $('#right').width(function () {
         return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - 85;
     });
```

Comment: Your fiddle link ... links to your account doesn't work

Comment: Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/9LGA9/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.outerWidth()` instead of `.width()`. I also replaced 85 with `$('#left').outerWidth() / 2` to make it more dynamic.

http://jsfiddle.net/9LGA9/11/

```
 function elasticCol() {
 $('#middle').outerWidth(function () {
     return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - $('#left').outerWidth() / 2;
 });

 $('#right').outerWidth(function () {
     return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - $('#left').outerWidth() / 2;
 });

 }
 elasticCol();

 $(window).on('resize', function () {
     elasticCol();
 });
```

Comment: No problem. Happens when you have too many fiddle links open in tab :P

Comment: Yep, or even worse, just increment the link by 1 after updating it.